# How to prevent grouped Listview children from collapsing when scrolling

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

On iOS, childrens of grouped Listview automatically collapse when scrolling. On android they doesnt.
Is there a way to prevent this behavior ?

Edit : here is a quick video to show you whats going on : https://streamable.com/eh4c5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Custom Renderer and set the **UITableViewStyle** as `Group`

```
using xxx.iOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using CoreGraphics;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(ListView),typeof(MyTableViewRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class MyTableViewRenderer:ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                var myTableView = new UITableView(this.Bounds, UITableViewStyle.Grouped)
                {
                    Source = Control.Source
                };
                SetNativeControl(myTableView);
            }

        }

    }
}
```